# php tcpdf not displaying accented characters from strftime

Tags: php, localization, locale, tcpdf, strftime

so I'm setting the locale with

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR");
```

and then using strftime like so

```
$membershipStartDate = strftime('%A le %e %B %G', strtotime($_POST['membershipStartDate']));
```

this is working but the spelling of August in french is wrong. It's outputting the %B as "aot" when it should be "août"

anybody have any ideas?

EDIT: it looks like it might be a problem with TCPDF. If I use the Write() method with accents in a string it works. But if I use the strftime() function those accents do not show up. Using strftime()
outside of TCPDF works as well.

```
$pdf->Write(0,'août','',0,'L',false,0,false,true,0); // accents output correctly
$pdf->Write(0,$membershipStartDate,'',0,'L',false,0,false,true,0); // doesn't show accents
```

Comment: What's the output encoding and did you encode it correctly?

Comment: it's being output in tcpdf and UTF-8 encoded

Comment: Did you tried to look into the generated HTML source code?

Comment: Must be an encoding problem, just tried on my localhost, I got `mardi le 28 août 2012`.

Comment: It must be a problem with tcpdf somehow. Any accented letters I have directly in my code output fine but it's just this variable that is generated by strftime that doesn't want to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping strftime() in utf8_encode() solved it. Not sure if it's a bug with strftime() or TCPDF.

```
$membershipStartDate = utf8_encode(strftime('%A le %e %B %G', strtotime($_POST['membershipStartDate'])));
```

Comment: Hi, your solution adding utf8_encode works on my live server but not on my development server. What could cause this difference? The previous situation was that the character was shown right on dev server and garbled on live server.